Connection between SDE and Doob-Meyer decomposition
Suppose that the stochastic process $(X_t)$ is the solution of the following SDE:
$$dX_t = f_t dt + h_tdW_t,$$
(where $W_t$ is the stanrdard Wiener process) so that with probability $1$, it equals to the integral process
$$X_t = \int_0^t f_s ds+ \int_0^t h_s dW_s, \,\, a.s.$$
Also suppose that $(X_t)$ admits a Doob-Meyer decomposition:
$$X_t = \Lambda_t+M_t$$
where $(\Lambda_t)$ is the compensator and $(M_t)$ is the martingale.
Then, do we have the following?
$$\Lambda_t = \int_0^t f_s ds,\,\, a.s., \quad M_t = \int_0^t h_s dW_s,\,\, a.s.$$
This looks reasonable to me since $\int_0^t h_s dW_s$ is a martingale and the Doob-Meyer decomposition is unique.

Find a reference paper. In pg. 3027, Graphical modeling of stochastic processes driven by correlated noise, the author said: "For any regular Ito process, $M_t$ is a martingale and $\Lambda_t$ is the compensator of $X_t$ in its Doob-Meyer decomposition".
